# Using R Shiny and ShinyFiles to have the user select a directory in their local machine and save their selection

Tags: r, shiny

The bottom code is supposed to have the user select a directory in their local machine and save their selection in **directory_path** but it doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton("directory", "Select Directory", "Please select a directory"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_directory")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(directory_path = NULL)
  
  selected_directory <- eventReactive(input$directory, {
    chosen_dir <- shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = c(home = '~'), filetypes = NULL)
    if (!is.null(chosen_dir)) {
      return(as.character(chosen_dir$value))
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    rv$directory_path <- selected_directory()
  })
  
  output$selected_directory <- renderText({
    paste0("You selected the following path: ", rv$directory_path)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried the pasted code but it seems like nothing got saved in **directory_path**

Comment: When `chosen_dir` is not `NULL`, your event reactive returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton("directory", "Select Directory", "Please select a directory"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_directory")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  roots <- c(home = '~')
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = roots, filetypes = NULL)
  
  output$selected_directory <- renderText({
    parseDirPath(roots, input$directory)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

In response to OP's comment:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton("directory", "Select Directory", "Please select a directory"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_directory")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  roots <- c(home = '~')
  rv <- reactiveValues(directory_path = NA)
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = roots, filetypes = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$directory, {
    rv$directory_path <- parseDirPath(roots, input$directory)
  })
  
  output$selected_directory <- renderText({
    rv$directory_path
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This work, but I need to create a reactive value (I think the wording is right....I'm new to shiny) so I can use the selected directory as an argument.

Comment: That's easily achieved.  See my edit.